# Why mock model method failed when run full suite

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have to change `.clean()` which has deep logic behind the scene.
Since it is not directly related to my feature I decided to mock it out and cut the complicate logic. Then I can use `mommy.make` to fulfill the testing objects.

Here is my code.
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/cfeadfbb29996823abfb998447cfe822

If I run them individually it works. But fail when run full suite.

I had follow these:
[why would a django test fail only when the full test suite is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792439/why-would-a-django-test-fail-only-when-the-full-test-suite-is-run) 
[Django unit tests failing when run with other test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481804/django-unit-tests-failing-when-run-with-other-test-cases) 
But does not work.

**My errors:**
2 last test cases fail

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1179, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/el/Code/eneos-pos-web/eneos/apps/mail_logs/mail_data_tests.py", line 194, in test_user_change_status_13July_query_all_false
    self.assertDictEqual(expected_obj, summary)
AssertionError: {'tod[71 chars] 0, 'today_active_email_true': 0, 'today_active_email_none': 1} != {'tod[71 chars] 0, 'today_active_email_true': 0, 'today_active_email_none': 0}
  {'today_active_email': 1,
   'today_active_email_false': 0,
-  'today_active_email_none': 1,
?                             ^

+  'today_active_email_none': 0,
?                             ^

   'today_active_email_true': 0,
   'today_all_orders': 1}


Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1179, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/el/Code/eneos-pos-web/eneos/apps/mail_logs/mail_data_tests.py", line 231, in test_user_change_status_16July
    self.assertDictEqual(expected_obj, summary)
AssertionError: {'today_active_email': 1, 'today_active_email_fals[84 chars]': 1} != {'today_all_orders': 1, 'today_active_email': 1, '[84 chars]': 0}
  {'today_active_email': 1,
   'today_active_email_false': 0,
-  'today_active_email_none': 1,
?                             ^

+  'today_active_email_none': 0,
?                             ^

   'today_active_email_true': 0,
   'today_all_orders': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure program logic has not bounded with sequence id.
However, to keep database back to the original state like individual runs.
I use the following config.

```
class MailLogFixture(TransactionTestCase):
    reset_sequences = True
```

And it works